# Activate a warning for int - float operation in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way to activate in gcc a warning for all the times that there is a int - float operation?
I have an old code with many arithmetic operation and I noticed that there are many situation like that:

```
int a, b, c;
double x, y, z;
y = a + x*b + c/z;
```

It is not easy to track all these situations with "search" tool of my ide, since the code is really long, cryptic and intricate (previous example is just given to figure out the problem)! So, I was wondering if there is a ***"-Wsomenthing"*** available in gcc that can help me with this drudgery.

**Addition**

I don't receive any warning with -Wconversion active

Comment: can you try -Wconversion ?

Comment: I don't see any problem that could come out of the above code - it will do exactly what you'd expect [assuming a, b, c and x, z are all initialized]. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm getting some bad values from this code and I'm looking for the problem inside the code. I checked that all formulas are well written into the code (I know the mathematical background behind the code so I have been able to do that). I noticed that there are a lot of situation as I described so I thought that it can be the problem.

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't get problems SOMETIMES from mixing floating point and integer calculations, but the above one doesn't show one of those, and in general, it's only when you convert double to integer, or use two integers in a divide that it causes problems. [Or integers overflow, of course].

Comment: @MatsPetersson the above code is just for figuring out the problem. The situation is more intricate than what I wrote.

Comment: I understand that it may be more complicated, but the rule is pretty much that as long as you don't divide two integers expecting the result to be a floating point value, everything will work [also assuming you don't use `float` rather than `double`, since you may lose precision that way, if you ever convert it back to int].

Comment: @MatsPetersson ok, thank you! I will try to look for some other kind of error in the code

Comment: Yes, I said that "assuming you don't use `float` rather than `double`, if you ever to convert it back to `int`". Actually they can be represented, just not 'precisely' represented. Stuffing `0x7fffffff` into a float will give you a value of approximately 2.047E+9, but converting it back to `int` will lose the last few digits, so it will come back as `0x7fffff00` or something similar. (Seems like the comment that this is a reply to disappeared...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably no such way, but your problem is a canonical case for GCC extensions or plugins.

You can extend GCC (version 4.6 or later) with plugins painfully coded in C. You can more easily extend GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC.

<sup>GCC 4.5 is extensible with plugins, but the plugins support is poor in 4.5, and better in 4.6 or 4.7 or soon to be released 4.8</sup>

If you use MELT, you probably want to use its `walk_gimple_seq_unique_tree` then match the current gimple with `gimple_assign_cast`.

<sup>Writing such a MELT extension might take you more than a day; the issue is that GCC is complex, and you need to partly understand its internal representation (Gimple), and its pass machinery. If you have a large code base customizing the compiler is still worth the effort.</sup>

Ask MELT specific questions on [gcc-melt@googlegroups.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/gcc-melt)

Comment: Maybe messing with clang ([LLVM](http://llvm.org)) turns out easier? Or even [sparse](https://sparse.wiki.kernel.org)?

Comment: I'm not sure of that. But you could try.. And the question mentioned specifically *gcc*

Comment: clang and sparse are explicitly very gcc-compatible. And you need whatever tool you set up just to find dubious code...

Comment: And I gave precise hints on what MELT constructs to use, so that should be fairly easy.